# Matrix/Rotation system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, rotations

Suppose you have the (known) 3x3 matrices A, B, C, and D and you also have the (known) 3D vectors a, b, c, and d. How would you go about finding the (unknown) matrix Q for which AQa = BQb = CQc = DQd?

I feel like there should be some elegant linear-algebra way of solving this but I haven't been able to come up with anything (except a possible, if ugly, numerical method). If it helps, you may assume that A, B, C, and D are rotation matrices.

Comment: You can always have $Q=0$. Otherwise $Q$ is not unique. If you have any $Q$, $2Q$ would also be a solution

Comment: Lol. Maybe I should add "non-trivial" to the problem statement. But now that I think about it, I'm worried that the problem may not be constrained enough or may even be over-constrained as the "D-d" pair might be unnecessary. What I'm really trying to do is convert between two coordinate systems when they are rotated together and I only have access to the components of one vector in the second coordinate system.

Comment: So you have the components of a vector $v$ in coordinate system $R$. And if you rotate somehow the coordinate system to $R'$, then the same vector is $v'$. And you want to know what is the transformation from $R$ to $R'$. Is that your problem? Or do you have multiple $v$ and $v'$ vectors?

Comment: I think you have the gist of it. There's technically 3 coordinate systems F_1, F_2, and F_3. F_1 is stationary. F_2 and F_3 are always rotated together. I always know how to convert F_2 to F_1 (matrices A, B, C, D) but I want to know how to convert F_3 to F_2 (the matrix Q). The only thing I have from F_3 though are the components of a vector that is always physically unchanged with respect to F_1 (vectors a, b, c, d).